# Is it possible to get the selector from a locator object in playwright?

Tags: javascript, automation, ui-automation, playwright

I'm using the page-object-model in developing my automated tests in playwright.  As such, I'm building a class to hold my locators and expose the locators, but not necessarily the used selector. Does the locator have a way to share its selector?

```
exports.MyWebPageModel = class MyWebPageModel {
  constructor(page) {
    this.myMultiSelect = page.locator('#select-group select');
    this.submitButton = page.locator('#submit-btn');
  }
}
```

```
test('validate multi-select submission', ({page}) -> {
  const myPage = new MyWebPageModel(page);
  const selectChoices = ['choice1', 'choice2', 'choice4'];
  await myPage.myMultiSelect.selectOptions(selectedChoices);
  Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    myPage.submitButton.click()
  ]);

  /* do tests on new page, click it's back button to return to previous page */

  const allSelectedValues = await page.$eval(myPage.myMultiSelect.???, e => Array.from(e.selectedOptions).map(option => option.value));  // get the selected options from select element
  expect(allSelectedValues).toEqual(selectedChoices);  // verify the selected options matches selectChoices.
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing the following:

```js
const myLoc = page.locator('#myElement');
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myLoc).forEach(prop => { 
  console.log(prop + " = " + row_locator[prop]); 
});
```

I was able to discover there is a `_selector`, which returns the internal selector used for the Locator object.

So the answer is to use the locator's "private" property `_selector`. This is the value that is used when generating a locator error.

So, given a table:

```html
<table id="colors">
  <thead>
  <trow>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>Color</th>
  </trow>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <trow>
    <td>R</td><td>Red</td>
  </trow>
  <trow>
    <td>B</td><td>Blue</td>
  </trow>
  <trow>
    <td>G</td><td>Green</td>
  </trow>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And, perhaps you build your playwright object as follows:

```js
exports.ColorTable = class ColorTable {
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.table = this.page.locator("#colors");
    this.tableData = this.table.locator('tbody tr');
  }
}
```

The result of the following

```js
const myT = new ColorTable(page);
console.log(myT.tableData._selector);
```

might look like:  `Locator@#colors >> tbody tr`

Comment: I found this useful. I was looking for a way to “add” one locator to another. Doing `oneLocator.locator(otherLocator._selector)` achieves what I need.

Comment: Does `_selector` also work in TS?

Comment: yes, @[jkalandarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8852720/jkalandarov), i tested in TS - that works `const selectorPath = myLocator['_selector']`

Answer (score 2):

Well this is one way, but not sure if it will work for all possible locators!.

```
// Get a selector from a playwright locator
import { Locator } from "@playwright/test";
export function extractSelector(locator: Locator) {
    const selector = locator.toString();
    const parts = selector.split("@");
    if (parts.length !== 2) { throw Error("extractSelector: susupect that this is not a locator"); }
    if (parts[0] !== "Locator") { throw Error("extractSelector: did not find locator"); }
    return parts[1];
}
```

Comment: That worked very well for me with Playwright version 1.37.1. In my case `locator.toString().replace("Locator@", "")` was sufficient. After Updating Playwright to 1.39.0 the `.toString()` has changed to `locator('...')`. This is how I solved the problem.
`let selector = locator.toString().replace("Locator@", "");`
`let locatorRegEx = new RegExp("(?![locatr('])[^.]*(?='\\)?)", "g");`
`let splitRegEx = new RegExp("(?![\(\']).*(?=\'\\)?)");`
`return locatorRegEx.test(selector) ? selector.split('locator').map(locator => locator.match(splitRegEx)).filter(Boolean).join(" >> ") : selector;`

Answer (score 0):

I am 95% sure that you can not get the selector which was previuously used. However there is way to get selector by changing your class and making the selectors as public class attributes.

```
exports.MyWebPageModel = class MyWebPageModel {

//think it can be declared as const
public let multiSelectSelector:string = '#select-group select';
public let submitButtonSelector:string = '#submit-btn';

  constructor(page) {
    this.myMultiSelect = page.locator(this.multiSelectLocator);
    this.submitButton = page.locator(this.submitButton);
  }
}
```

Comment: close, it's `static mySelector = 'selector string';`. I've thought about doing something like that.